# Jackson Custom Deserialization for Mapping Class Name String to Actual Class Definition

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I am using Jackson custom Deserializers to parse a JSON file. In this file there are bunch of entries with key "class" and value the name of the class (without the full package name). The deserializer knows a bunch of predefined (hard) paths to search for the any class. The custom deserializer should look for the keyword "class" (while its parsing the JSON) and then based on the value (the class name string), search in the predefined paths and instantiate an object with the matching class name.

I have implemented the Jackson `Deserializers` interface and have overridden a bunch of callbacks: `findBeanDeserializer`, `findBeanDeserializer`, `findEnumDeserializer`...
However this does not let me catch the event when the  parser sees the `class:ClassName` key-value pair and act differently based on that.

Any help or pointers will be deeply appreciated.

An example JSON

```
{
    "class": "X",
    "fieldName1": {
        "class": "Y",
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) or [this](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) help?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you haven't spend too much time writing custom stuff. What you can use, out of the box, is to annotation `@JsonTypeInfo` (see [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)): it makes Jackson automatically read/write additional type information. And one possible inclusion mechanism is `As.PROPERTY`, in which case class name (or type name) is added as virtual property to use.
Name of property can be customized as well.